# SAPUI5 Multimodel Binding

Tags: model-binding, sapui5

I have a problem with multimodel binding.

In init function of controller i set JSON model in ui.core

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(data1);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "model1");
```

in View I have a template of ColumnListItem and I bind it in a table

```
    var template = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
          id: "first_template",
          type: "Navigation",
          type : sap.m.ListType.Active,
          visible: true,
          selected: true,
          cells: [ new sap.m.Label({
                    text: "{name}"
                    })
          ],
          press: [oController.pressListMethod]


  });

   oTable.bindItems("model1>/events", template, null, null);
   oPage.addContent(oTable);
```

With simple Model it work's rigth but in Multimodel table only gets the number of items but not the properties of the model. Any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the model name in the template, too:

```
var template = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
  id: "first_template",
  type: "Navigation",
  type : sap.m.ListType.Active,
  visible: true,
  selected: true,
  cells: [ 
    new sap.m.Label({
      text: "{model1>name}" // No leading "/" here since the binding is relative to the aggregation binding below
    })
  ],
  press: oController.pressListMethod
});

oTable.bindItems("model1>/events", template);
oPage.addContent(oTable);
```